# Setting a session in steps

Tags: php, session

Is it possible to set multiple session elements to the same session at different times? I have 2 classes and each class should set 2 session elements. What I'm getting back is an empty array. I am using `session_start()` on each page.

Also, I can set the session successfully from within a single class, but get an empty array back when setting from each class.

```
// User class
$_SESSION['user'] = array('id' => 1);
$_SESSION['user'] = array('name' => 'Tim Miller');

// Part class
$_SESSION['user'] = array('model' => '12311');
$_SESSION['user'] = array('part' => 'AA34F');
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the array I would like to create:

```
Array (
  [user] => Array (
    [id] => 1
    [name] => Tim Miller
    [model] => 12311
    [part] => AA34F
    [order] => 119026
    [serial] => 12001923S3
  )
)
```

Elements 0 and 1 should be set in the user class
Elements 2-3 should be set in the part class
Elements 4-5 should be set in the serial class

Comment: It doesn't matter where you set session variables. Something else is causing this issue. Can you expand a little more on where/how you're setting this data? Also, do you know that you're overwriting the `user` session variable in each of those cases?

Comment: @waterloomatt, thanks. I also think that maybe something else is causing this issue but wanted to ask to verify. I am trying to simply add elements to a session array at different times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it but bit different approach need to be used. You can create an array of sessions with different values.

You have to write session_start() on top of each file where you need to use session.

```
session_start();

// User class
$_SESSION['user'][] = array('id' => 1);
$_SESSION['user'][] = array('name' => 'Tim Miller');

// Part class
$_SESSION['user'][] = array('model' => '12311');
$_SESSION['user'][] = array('part' => 'AA34F');

print_r( $_SESSION['user'] );
```

Output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Tim Miller
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [model] => 12311
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [part] => AA34F
        )
)
```

It's upto you how do you want to crate this array.

**EDIT:**

To get your desire format output and add values to array later in different files you can give a try like:

```
// Your code here!
session_start();

// User class
$_SESSION['user'][] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Tim Miller');

// Part class
$key = -1
$key = array_search( 1, array_column($_SESSION['user'], 'id') );
// Here 1 in array_search is id of user your can use $id to add data to correct user's by id.

if( $key > -1 ) {
    $_SESSION['user'][ $key ] = array_merge( $_SESSION['user'][ $key ], array('model' => '12311', 'part' => 'AA34F') );
}


print_r( $_SESSION['user'] );
```

This will give you following output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Tim Miller
            [model] => 12311
            [part] => AA34F
        )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Vantiya. I've edited my post to show more of what I'm looking for,

Comment: Ok. How does your work for different users? I mean, you're setting session at different file so you need to keep track of user as well. BTW did above solutions works for you?

Comment: I think I forgot to use `session_start` on the top of the page where I'm setting the vars. It's working now. Thanks Vantiya.